# Limiting DatabaseMail sending rate

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

We are using DatabaseMail of SQLServer to send our mails. 
But our e-mail server provider is allowing us to send 5 e-mails per second, the other ones are simply rejected.

I need to figure out throttling DatabaseMail.

Comment: If you are logging the email transactions, could you perhaps look at the last 5 records added to the log and see if the timestamp is the same as now and then do a sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good approach is to create a queue.  This has an added benefit of creating an email log.

DDL Script

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    sys.objects o
                    JOIN sys.schemas s ON ( s.schema_id = o.schema_id )
            WHERE   s.name = 'dbo'
                    AND o.name = 'dbmail_queue'
                    AND o.type = 'U' )
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[dbmail_queue]
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.dbmail_queue
    (
      dbmail_queue_id BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL ,
      profile_name SYSNAME NULL ,
      recipients VARCHAR(MAX) NULL ,
      copy_recipients VARCHAR(MAX) NULL ,
      blind_copy_recipients VARCHAR(MAX) NULL ,
      from_address VARCHAR(MAX) NULL ,
      reply_to VARCHAR(MAX) NULL ,
      [subject] NVARCHAR(255) NULL ,
      body NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL ,
      body_format VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
      importance VARCHAR(6) NULL ,
      sensitivity VARCHAR(12) NULL ,
      file_attachments NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL ,
      query NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL ,
      execute_query_database SYSNAME NULL ,
      attach_query_result_as_file BIT NULL ,
      query_attachment_filename NVARCHAR(255) NULL ,
      query_result_header BIT NULL ,
      query_result_width INT NULL ,
      query_result_separator CHAR(1) NULL ,
      exclude_query_output BIT NULL ,
      append_query_error BIT NULL ,
      query_no_truncate BIT NULL ,
      query_result_no_padding BIT NULL ,
      mailitem_id INT NULL ,
      mail_sent BIT NOT NULL ,
      mail_queued_time DATETIME NOT NULL ,
      mail_sent_time DATETIME NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT pk_dbmail_queue PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( dbmail_queue_id ASC )
    );
GO
```

Stored Procedure Scripts

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    sys.objects o
                    JOIN sys.schemas s ON ( s.schema_id = o.schema_id )
            WHERE   s.name = 'dbo'
                    AND o.name = 'usp_queue_dbmail'
                    AND o.type = 'P' )
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_queue_dbmail]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_queue_dbmail
    @profile_name SYSNAME = NULL ,
    @recipients VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL ,
    @copy_recipients VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL ,
    @blind_copy_recipients VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL ,
    @from_address VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL ,
    @reply_to VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL ,
    @subject NVARCHAR(255) = NULL ,
    @body NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL ,
    @body_format VARCHAR(20) = NULL ,
    @importance VARCHAR(6) = NULL ,
    @sensitivity VARCHAR(12) = NULL ,
    @file_attachments NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL ,
    @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL ,
    @execute_query_database SYSNAME = NULL ,
    @attach_query_result_as_file BIT = NULL ,
    @query_attachment_filename NVARCHAR(255) = NULL ,
    @query_result_header BIT = NULL ,
    @query_result_width INT = NULL ,
    @query_result_separator CHAR(1) = NULL ,
    @exclude_query_output BIT = NULL ,
    @append_query_error BIT = NULL ,
    @query_no_truncate BIT = NULL ,
    @query_result_no_padding BIT = NULL
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT  INTO [dbo].[dbmail_queue]
            ( [profile_name] ,
              [recipients] ,
              [copy_recipients] ,
              [blind_copy_recipients] ,
              [from_address] ,
              [reply_to] ,
              [subject] ,
              [body] ,
              [body_format] ,
              [importance] ,
              [sensitivity] ,
              [file_attachments] ,
              [query] ,
              [execute_query_database] ,
              [attach_query_result_as_file] ,
              [query_attachment_filename] ,
              [query_result_header] ,
              [query_result_width] ,
              [query_result_separator] ,
              [exclude_query_output] ,
              [append_query_error] ,
              [query_no_truncate] ,
              [query_result_no_padding] ,
              [mail_sent] ,
              [mail_queued_time]
            )
    VALUES  ( @profile_name ,
              @recipients ,
              @copy_recipients ,
              @blind_copy_recipients ,
              @from_address ,
              @reply_to ,
              @subject, 
              @body ,
              @body_format ,
              @importance ,
              @sensitivity ,
              @file_attachments ,
              @query ,
              @execute_query_database ,
              @attach_query_result_as_file ,
              @query_attachment_filename ,
              @query_result_header ,
              @query_result_width ,
              @query_result_separator ,
              @exclude_query_output ,
              @append_query_error ,
              @query_no_truncate ,
              @query_result_no_padding ,
              0 ,
              GETDATE()
            )
GO
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    sys.objects o
                    JOIN sys.schemas s ON ( s.schema_id = o.schema_id )
            WHERE   s.name = 'dbo'
                    AND o.name = 'usp_send_dbmail_queue'
                    AND o.type = 'P' )
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_send_dbmail_queue]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_send_dbmail_queue @QueueSize INT = '5', @Delay VARCHAR(12) = '00:00:01'
AS
    DECLARE @dbmail_queue_id BIGINT ,
        @profile_name SYSNAME ,
        @recipients VARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @copy_recipients VARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @blind_copy_recipients VARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @from_address VARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @reply_to VARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @subject NVARCHAR(255) ,
        @body NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @body_format VARCHAR(20) ,
        @importance VARCHAR(6) ,
        @sensitivity VARCHAR(12) ,
        @file_attachments NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @query NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @execute_query_database SYSNAME ,
        @attach_query_result_as_file BIT ,
        @query_attachment_filename NVARCHAR(255) ,
        @query_result_header BIT ,
        @query_result_width INT ,
        @query_result_separator CHAR(1) ,
        @exclude_query_output BIT ,
        @append_query_error BIT ,
        @query_no_truncate BIT ,
        @query_result_no_padding BIT ,
        @mailitem_id INT


    DECLARE queue_cursor CURSOR
    FOR
        SELECT TOP ( @QueueSize )
                dbmail_queue_id
        FROM    dbo.dbmail_queue
        WHERE   mail_sent = 0
        ORDER BY mail_queued_time DESC

    OPEN queue_cursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM queue_cursor INTO @dbmail_queue_id

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

            SELECT  @profile_name = profile_name ,
                    @recipients = recipients ,
                    @copy_recipients = copy_recipients ,
                    @blind_copy_recipients = blind_copy_recipients ,
                    @from_address = from_address ,
                    @reply_to = reply_to ,
                    @subject = COALESCE([subject],'SQL Server Message') ,
                    @body = body ,
                    @body_format = body_format ,
                    @importance = COALESCE(importance, 'Normal') ,
                    @sensitivity = COALESCE(sensitivity, 'Normal') ,
                    @file_attachments = file_attachments ,
                    @query = query ,
                    @execute_query_database = execute_query_database ,
                    @attach_query_result_as_file = COALESCE(attach_query_result_as_file, 0) ,
                    @query_attachment_filename = query_attachment_filename ,
                    @query_result_header = COALESCE(query_result_header, 1) ,
                    @query_result_width = query_result_width ,
                    @query_result_separator = COALESCE(query_result_separator, ' ') ,
                    @exclude_query_output = COALESCE(exclude_query_output, 0) ,
                    @append_query_error = COALESCE(append_query_error, 0) ,
                    @query_no_truncate = query_no_truncate ,
                    @query_result_no_padding = query_result_no_padding
            FROM    dbo.dbmail_queue
            WHERE   dbmail_queue_id = @dbmail_queue_id

            BEGIN TRY 

                SET NOCOUNT ON 

                IF @@VERSION LIKE 'Microsoft SQL Server 2005%'
                    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = @profile_name,
                        @recipients = @recipients,
                        @copy_recipients = @copy_recipients,
                        @blind_copy_recipients = @blind_copy_recipients,
                        --@from_address is not a Microsoft SQL Server 2005 parameter
                        --@reply_to is not a Microsoft SQL Server 2005 parameter
                        @subject = @subject, @body = @body,
                        @body_format = @body_format, @importance = @importance,
                        @sensitivity = @sensitivity,
                        @file_attachments = @file_attachments, @query = @query,
                        @execute_query_database = @execute_query_database,
                        @attach_query_result_as_file = @attach_query_result_as_file,
                        @query_attachment_filename = @query_attachment_filename,
                        @query_result_header = @query_result_header,
                        @query_result_width = @query_result_width,
                        @query_result_separator = @query_result_separator,
                        @exclude_query_output = @exclude_query_output,
                        @append_query_error = @append_query_error,
                        @query_no_truncate = @query_no_truncate,
                        @query_result_no_padding = @query_result_no_padding,
                        @mailitem_id = @mailitem_id OUTPUT;
                ELSE
                    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = @profile_name,
                        @recipients = @recipients,
                        @copy_recipients = @copy_recipients,
                        @blind_copy_recipients = @blind_copy_recipients,
                        @from_address = @from_address, @reply_to = @reply_to,
                        @subject = @subject, @body = @body,
                        @body_format = @body_format, @importance = @importance,
                        @sensitivity = @sensitivity,
                        @file_attachments = @file_attachments, @query = @query,
                        @execute_query_database = @execute_query_database,
                        @attach_query_result_as_file = @attach_query_result_as_file,
                        @query_attachment_filename = @query_attachment_filename,
                        @query_result_header = @query_result_header,
                        @query_result_width = @query_result_width,
                        @query_result_separator = @query_result_separator,
                        @exclude_query_output = @exclude_query_output,
                        @append_query_error = @append_query_error,
                        @query_no_truncate = @query_no_truncate,
                        @query_result_no_padding = @query_result_no_padding,
                        @mailitem_id = @mailitem_id OUTPUT;

                UPDATE  dq
                SET     mailitem_id = @mailitem_id ,
                        mail_sent = 1 ,
                        mail_sent_time = GETDATE()
                FROM    dbo.dbmail_queue dq
                WHERE   dq.dbmail_queue_id = @dbmail_queue_id

            END TRY 
            BEGIN CATCH 

                DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) ,
                    @ErrorSeverity INT ,
                    @ErrorState INT;
                SELECT  @ErrorMessage = 'Mail not sent.  ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() ,
                        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY() ,
                        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
                RAISERROR (
        @ErrorMessage,
        @ErrorSeverity,
        @ErrorState    
        );

            END CATCH 


            FETCH NEXT FROM queue_cursor INTO @dbmail_queue_id
        END

    CLOSE queue_cursor
    DEALLOCATE queue_cursor

    WAITFOR DELAY @Delay

GO
```

Rather than executing sp_send_dbmail, use usp_queue_dbmail.

Create a SQL Agent job that consists of one step.  usp_send_dbmail_queue

You can schedule the job to run every 1 second.